# Symfony 2 Services for Business Logic?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm currently developing a simple web application with Symfony 2 that process orders with products and lines of orders. Actually I have three Doctrine entities (Product, Line and Order). I will work with the data of these models and I need filter by date, add, delete, list, and make some administrative things with all the data.

As far I know this will be Service territory and is best practice to keep the controller away from doing this.

My question really is if I need to create ONE class with the methods that I need for all operations and then call them from the Controller, or create one Service class for each Doctrine Model (OrderManager, LineManager...) or orient more to task specific (RecountTotal, FilterDate...) But with the last method I think that each Service will have only one method inside.

Which is the best practice for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are totally correct in stating this is NOT a job for controller.

It's totally fine to use only one manager to contain all your data access methods.

```
class BaseManager { // Name it as you like
    ...
}
```

If you find yourself having very similar methods for different entities, you may want to split into different managers (OrderManager, LineManager, ProductManager) and have them extend a common BaseManager to reduce code duplication.

Additional classes for filters and counting should not be necessary unless you have some advanced requirements.

Comment: And for example, some functions that I want to implement are typical (find X id, or filter by date...). All of these things using Doctrine are some lines, so I'm creating methods for all these tasks in order to simplify the process. I'm creating them on the BaseManager class, but I think that this is part of the model and not Service/Controller part... For example using Eloquent instead of Doctrine, all these methods are static implemented on the Model. It's a good practice implementing filters on a Service? Thanks!

Comment: I am not able to suggest a best practice here. You have many choices and you can arrange things as you prefer. Even the official Symfony Best Practices are very relaxed about where you should put your business logic, once we all agree it should not be in the controllers.